# How can you get a local filesystem link of an offline-accessible PDF file in Dropbox?

Tags: file-system, pdf, dropbox, hyperlinks

I would like to get a link to a pdf file in my local Dropbox of my android. 
This is because I want to access the file by the syntax `/local/system/something/file.pdf#page=116` in Internet Browser. 
I have the file as *Available for Offline Use* in Dropbox. 
I do not know if this stores the file as readable in my system.

This would help me a lot because then I do not need to browse books at the very beginning of the file. The Dropbox browser is so limited that I cannot add there `#page=116` in Dropbox's pdf browser so I need a link to the file in the filesystem.

How can you get a local filesystem link of an offline-accessible PDF file in Dropbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in

```
YourLocalStorage/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/uXXXXXX/scratch/Your/Folder/In/Dropbox/file.pdf
```

Note that `YourLocalStorage` depends on your mobile. For example, it is `storage/emulated/0/` on some LG phones.

To access the file from your web browser you have to put `file:///` before the given path.

Comment: @Masi you can use some file manager to get the full path of a file. E.g. ES File Explorer